# Como associar objetos ao vértices de um grafo?

Tags: python-3.x, grafo

Estou estudando a respeito da teoria dos grafos, mais especificadamente sobre os [vértices](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A9rtice_(teoria_dos_grafos)) que são unidades que representam um determinado nó de um grafo. No entanto, ainda há algumas dúvidas em relação aos vértices.

Veja este grafo de ilustração em Python:

```
graph = {
  'A': ['B', 'C', 'D'],  
  'B': ['A'],
  'C': ['A', 'D'],
  'D': ['A', 'C']
}
```

Perceba que ele é um grafo não-direcionado, o dicionário guarda o caminho para cada vértice.

A minha dúvida está relacionada ao vértice, se é possível fazer com que ele represente um *objeto* ou uma *classe*. E o objeto que eu gostaria que meu vértice representasse seria do tipo da classe `Ambiente`:

```
class Ambiente:
  def __init__(self, titulo, descricao, id):
    self.titulo = titulo
    self.descricao = descricao
    self.id = id
```

Eu tentei associar o índice no dicionário:

```
ambientes = {
  'A': Ambiente('Sala de maquinas', 
       "A sala contém várias maquinas industriais, todas parecem não funcionar por anos. O som que é emitido dela é fantasmagórico e causa um estado de panico e alerta, como se a qualquer momento alguma entidade fosse emergir daquela pilha de metal amaldiçoada. Há poucos ruídos, no entanto, não há sinal de vida alguma.", 
       'A'
  )
}
```

Mas me parece não ser efetivo desta forma, ainda mais quando eu for precisar navegar pelos caminhos do grafo. Sendo assim, eu gostaria que minha pergunta abaixo seja respondida.

## Pergunta

Como eu poderia associar objetos aos vértices do grafo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se esta solução lhe agrada:

```
class Ambiente:
  def __init__(self, titulo, descricao, id):
    self.titulo = titulo
    self.descricao = descricao
    self.id = id

A = Ambiente('Sala de maquinas', 
       "A sala contém várias maquinas industriais e bla bla bla", 
       'A'
       )

B = Ambiente('Salão de Festas', 
       "Só fica quem sabe dançar, beber e se divertir!!", 
       'B'
       )

C = Ambiente('Banheiro', 
       "J-a escovou os dentes antes de dormir?", 
       'C'
       )

D = Ambiente('Jardim', 
       "Não coma muitos desses cogumelos ou você terá alucinações...", 
       'D'
       )

grafo = {
  A: [B, C, D],  
  B: [A],
  C: [A, D],
  D: [A, C]
}
```

Agora temos um grafo com objetos do tipo Ambiente, não apenas strings. Podemos até fazer uma função: (Edit: seguindo a sugestão do Isac)

```
def printa_grafo(grafo):
    print ("{")
    for key, value in grafo.items():
        print("  {}: [{}]".format(key.id, ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.id, value))))
    print ("}")

>>> printa_grafo(grafo)
{
  B: [A]
  D: [A, C]
  A: [B, C, D]
  C: [A, D]
}
```

Comment: O `for` que constrói a `string` é basicamente um `join` e consequentemente pode ser substituído por `string += ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.id, value))`. Pessoalmente eu substituia tudo o que está dentro do primeiro `for` por um único `print`, assim: `print("    {}: [{}]".format(key.id, ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.id, value))))`. Em acrescento os `str` que estão também não são necessários pois `key.id` já é uma `string`

Comment: @Isac, obrigado pela sugestão :) . Até editei minha resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite amigo.

De inicio voce esta tentanto referenciar uma classe não istanciada,
  oque pode ser feito a esse respeito é voce istanciar essa classe em uma variavel e depois usar essa variavel como "valor" de uma chave nesse dicionario do Grafo.

mais ou menos assim

```
class Ambiente:
  def __init__(self, titulo, descricao, id):
    self.titulo = titulo
    self.descricao = descricao
    self.id = id

  def __str__(self):
        return "%s, %s, %s" % self.titulo,self.descricao,self.id
```

**Instanciando a classe:**

```
  verticeAmbiente = Ambiente('Sala de maquinas', 
           "A sala contém várias maquinas industriais, todas parecem não funcionar por anos. O som que é emitido dela é fantasmagórico e causa um estado de panico e alerta, como se a qualquer momento alguma entidade fosse emergir daquela pilha de metal amaldiçoada. Há poucos ruídos, no entanto, não há sinal de vida alguma.", 
           'A')
```

**Depois:**

```
Ambiente = {'A': verticeAmbiente}
```

Como foi implementado o metodo `__str__` dentro da classe, ele imprime tudos o atributos do objeto passados no ***construtor***.

se quizer ver é só:

```
print(Ambiente['A'])
```

Em "tése", (até porque nunca precisei assim)

mas espero que ajude.

referencia https://penseallen.github.io/PensePython2e/17-classes-metodos.html